# Meta description not displaying in custom site search results page

Tags: google-programmable-search-engine

We have Google Custom Site Search implemented on our company website. When I'm looking at the results page, I noticed that the meta description is not being displayed. It just seems to be reading the links titles from our drop down menu and using this as a description.

When I search for the same page via `google.com`, the meta description is pulled in correctly.

Any thoughts why this might be happening.

I can't see anything in the Custom Site Search settings.

Comment: Please clarify: "instead it just seems to be reading the information from our drop down menu." (It's common for Google search results to take a snippet from the page if they feel it is more relevant to the search query entered instead of the meta description).

Comment: @GeoffJackson I've updated my post, hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is your meta description. If you put meta descriptions with full keywords without meaning, Google would thing that you are trying to stuff keywords in meta description and they would take the description from the page if they consider it is more related to the search keyword. Don't always use your keywords in description and just describe the page with some keywords.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a meta description tag with a phrase or two that have real and logical meaning to a real user, not completely "optimized" with keywords!

That's why Google considering the tag irrelevant and takes from the viewable content.